# Jquery callback after a drop

Tags: jquery

In this fiddle [http://jsfiddle.net/mjmitche/gq6En/31/](http://jsfiddle.net/mjmitche/gq6En/31), you can drag the orange box and drop it into the white box.

1. I am trying to create a call back function that starts after the drop. For example, can you fadeOut the small blue box once the orange box is dropped into the white box?  I dont care if a proper call back is used, or if there is some other way to trigger the new fadeOut function. I`m just trying to create a chain of events.
2. Also, the tutorial I got the jquery from did not use a z-index on the elements. However, when I dragged the orange box into the white box, it did notshow up until I put a z-index of 2 on it (i.e. the orange box was hidden underneath)  Is there a change I could make to my html so that I don`t have to use the z-index?

I`m a bit of a newbie, so I would appreciate if you could show me on jsfiddle how to set up the call back that takes effect on the drop.

Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
drop: function (event, ui) {
    $(this)
        .addClass ("ui-state-highlight")
        .find ("p")
        .html("dropped");
    $("#blue").fadeOut(); //This lines fades out after the drop
 }
```

Or, the same more 'callback' style:

```
drop: function (event, ui) {
            $(this)
                .addClass ("ui-state-highlight")
                .find ("p")
                .html("dropped");
            droppedOnWhite();
         }

function droppedOnWhite(){
  $("#blue").fadeOut(); //This lines fades out after the drop;
}
```

I've updated your fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/gq6En/46/

Hope this helps. Cheers

Comment: Thanks a lot. Did you happen to know the answer to the second question about the z-index?